# Is there an easy way of seeing that this sum is $0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic, products

Let $a,b,c,d$ be real positive numbers. Is there an easy way of seeing that

$$(c-d)(b-d)(b-c)-(c-d)(a-d)(a-c)+(b-d)(a-d)(a-b)-(b-c)(a-c)(a-b)=0 $$

without doing the whole multiplication ?

Comment: Without expanding the whole expression, you can try extracting one term from each product, check where else it occurs, and determine that it cancels with a negative copy from another product. For example, the first product $(\color{red}c-d)(\color{red}b-d)(\color{red}b-c)$ contributes $c\times b\times b=b^2c$, while the last product $\color{red}{-}(\color{red}b-c)(a\color{red}{-c})(a\color{red}{-b})$ contributes $-b\times(-c)\times(-b)=-b^2c$.

Comment: @user170231: this is the same amount of work as expanding the product.

Comment: This identity is `id4_4_1_3a` in my list of [Special Algebraic Identities](http://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/~somos/ident04.gp). It is a limiting case of a Jacobi elliptic function identity. The identity is valid in any commutative ring.

Comment: @Somos Very interesting, can you expand on the Jacobi comment ? Is there a $n$ variables version that is also connected to Jacobi elliptic function ?

Comment: @W.Volante If you read the comments before the `id4_4_1_3a` identity you will see that is just a special case of a more general identity published by Chamberland and Zeilberger. The next comment is from an article by Glaisher with the Jacobi elliptic sn identity. I don't know if there is a $n$ variable version of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! Pick your favorite variable, say $a$, and treat the expression as a polynomial in $a$ (with coefficients that are themselves polynomials in $b,c,d$). It's easy to check that this polynomial has degree at most $2$; but it's also easy to check that it vanishes at $b$, $c$, and $d$ and thus has at least three roots. Therefore it must be the zero polynomial.

Comment: This is an outstanding answer and I wish I could upvote it more than once.

Comment: So elegant, I love it!

Comment: Note that the three roots $b,c,d$ must be distinct if we want to conclude the zero polynomial.

Comment: @Sil: True, but think of $b,c,d$ not as numbers but as actual variables, so that they are automatically distinct.

Comment: Right, or we can deal with them not being distinct at the beginning. I guess my issue with looking at them as variables is that it might lead people to think of multivariate polynomials, but those can have infinitely many zeroes yet not be identically zero.

Comment: The most convenient way to view the polynomial in this context is as an element of $\Bbb R(b,c,d)[a]$, the polynomial ring in one variable over the field $\Bbb R(b,c,d)$. (The fact that $\Bbb R(b,c,d)$ is the field of fractions of another polynomial ring $\Bbb R[b,c,d]$ might appear to muddy the waters, but a field is a field is a field.)

Answer (score 0):

Write it as$$\begin{align}&\int_a^b(c-d)[2x-c-d]\mathrm{d}x+\int_c^d(a-b)[2y-a-b]\mathrm{d}y\\&=\int_a^b\mathrm{d}x\int_c^d\mathrm{d}y\{2x+2y-a-b-c-d\}.\end{align}$$The symmetry $x\to(a+b) /2-x,\,y\to(c+d)/2-y$ make the rest obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Making two variables equal makes two products vanish and makes the remaining two cancel each other. E.g. with $a=b$, the equation turns to the identity

$$(c-d)(b-d)(b-c)-(c-d)(b-d)(b-c)\equiv 0.$$ Hence the given expression is of the form

$$P(a,b,c,d)(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(b-c)(b-d)(c-d).$$

Because of the degrees, $P(a,b,c,d)\equiv 0$.